# And the fete at the English ambassador's?

Tags: possessives

[the SOURCE](https://books.google.jo/books?id=RvXTCgAAQBAJ&pg=PT5&dq=and%20the%20fete%20at%20the%20english%20ambassadors?%20today%20is%20wednesday&hl=ar&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjupNHGq-TWAhXhAMAKHfvvA3QQ6AEIIjAA#v=onepage&q=and%20the%20fete%20at%20the%20english%20ambassadors%3F%20today%20is%20wednesday&f=false) WAR AND PEACE

> "And the fete at the English **ambassador's**? Today is Wednesday.

"S" is of possession, means should ambassador followed by a noun.

Where is the noun?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The possessive case of a person's name, title or occupation is often used to designate their home or place of business.

> There's a party tonight at **Mary's**.
>   I have an appointment at **Dr. Fisher's**.
>   Mrs. Schmidt is over at the Chairman's; she should be back in half an hour or so.

Comment: Thank you. I also saw this "to be an enthusiast had become her social vocation" isn't it the same as: "to be an enthusiast, she had become..."?

Comment: @BavyanYaldo - That should be a separate question, but no, it's not the same.  Think of it as "Her social vocation was being an enthusiast."

Comment: It's best to ask a new question as a question, rather than in a comment, @BavyanYaldo, but I'll answer: no. The subject of the sentence (the thing that had become a social vocation) is "To be an enthusiast". Your paraphrase has quite a different meaning, where "To be an enthusiast" is the purpose.